Spring Boot Application Runs in IntelliJ IDEA but Fails with mvn install Due to JDBC URL Error
I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application. It runs perfectly fine when I start it directly from IntelliJ IDEA by clicking the play button. However, when I try to build the project using mvn clean install, I encounter an error indicating that the URL must start with 'jdbc'. This error appears in the Surefire reports.
Here's the main class of my application:
package com.ampliamasnotas.usuarios_api;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UsuariosApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Imprimir variables de entorno
       String dbUrl = System.getenv("DB_URL");
       String dbUser = System.getenv("DB_USER");
       String dbPw = System.getenv("DB_PW");

       System.out.println("DB_URL: " + dbUrl);
       System.out.println("DB_USER: " + dbUser);
       System.out.println("DB_PW: " + dbPw);

       SpringApplication.run(UsuariosApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Here's the application.properties:
spring.application.name=usuarios_api
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PW}
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8080

These are the environment variables I've set in the IntelliJ IDEA configuration:
DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/user?createIfNotExists=true&serverTimezone=UTC;DB_USER=root;DB_PW=123456
The dependencies I included in Spring Initializr are:
Spring Web, Spring Data JPA, MYSQL Driver.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that my environment variables are correctly set during mvn clean install?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
I've read that there should be no spaces or quotes around the environment variable values, and I have ensured this is the case. The application runs fine directly from IntelliJ IDEA, but it seems like the environment variables are not being picked up during the Maven build process.

You can create for example database.properties file to store the DB conf there: DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/user?createIfNotExists=true&serverTimezone=UTC
DB_USER=root
DB_PW=123456. Then load the properties file in your application: @Value("${DB_URL}")     private String dbUrl; . . . and other values inside a java class   

If you do use mvn clean install as a command in the terminal, its explainable: environment where you run it, does not contain such environment variables

The issue arises when running mvn clean install: the variables are not being passed to the JVM executing your tests. You have two options to address this:

Skip tests : Run mvn clean install with the "Skip tests" mode enabled.
Configure the Maven Surefire Plugin:
Update your pom.xml to include the necessary system properties for the Maven Surefire Plugin:



...
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <DB_URL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/user?createIfNotExists=true&serverTimezone=UTC</DB_URL>
                    <DB_USER>root</DB_USER>
                    <DB_PW>123456</DB_PW>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
...

